# Need to read the RSVP status of ICS invites I generate from the backend

Tags: icalendar

I am working on a portal which sends out calendar invites (ICS) to participants. I am able to generate the calendar invites, specify the organizer and participants and send them to the participants using a mailing service (no-reply). The recipients are able to RSVP the invites as well, but the RSVP status is only reflected on the calendars of the people invited.

However, I need to be able to read the RSVP status to display it on the website as well. How can this be done?

Not sure if there is a way to read the RSVP status being one of the invitees.